# Can't import directory in filecoin lotus node

Tags: filecoin, filecoin-lotus

I am running a lotus client, but when I run:

```
lotus client import <path/to/directory>
```

I get:

```
ERROR: failed to import file using unixfs: failed to import file to store to compute root: read /home/patrick_alphachain_io/code/unstoppable-ui/unstoppable-ui-static-export: is a directory
```

Can we not upload directories like we can with IPFS? Is there a way to just upload an IPFS CID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your folder into a `.car` file and upload that to filecoin.

You could use a tool like [ipfs-car](https://github.com/web3-storage/ipfs-car).

```
yarn ipfs-car --pack /path/to/directory/ --output my-output.car
```

And then upload that to filecoin

```
lotus client import --car my-output.car
```